# Serializing and Deserializing of Sorbet T::Struct

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I recently started playing around with Sorbet and stumbled upon [T::Struct](https://sorbet.org/docs/tstruct) which seems pretty useful for type safe value only objects.

One example could be:

```rb
class Order < T::Struct
  prop :order_id, String
  prop :amount, Integer
  prop :currency, String

  prop :submitted_at, DateTime
end
```

This can then be easily instantiated via:

```rb
order = Order.new(order_id: "ORD-001", amount: 100, currency: "USD", submitted_at: DateTime.now)
```

However I also wanted to persist these objects in a file or database. Luckily serialization to json is pretty straightforward:

```rb
File.open("#{order.order_id}.json", "wb"){|f| f.write(order.to_json)}
```

But when it comes to deserialization it becomes pretty tricky (for JSON) as the date is saved as a string. Doing a `JSON.load` and the symbolizing the keys won't do it.

So I was wondering, is there already a serializer that checks all values against the types and makes it possible to provide a mapper for types that don't match?

Comment: Check out `Marshal`. Also, YAML supports `Date`s

Comment: Also appears that you could use this property syntax on any object you wanted (meaning define your own persistence mechanism) because  `T::Struct` is mostly just a collection of methods from other Modules [See Here](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/master/gems/sorbet-runtime/lib/types/struct.rb)

Answer (score 2):

For the simpler cases maybe `#from_hash` can do the trick. This takes a string-keys hash.

Another thing you could take a look at is `TypedParams` from the `sorbet-rails` gem if you are using rails of course. If not, maybe you can use `TypeCoerce` from `sorbet-coerce` to create something useful.